# Static Imports in Java

Tags: java, compilation

```
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static java.lang.Long.*;

public class StaticImortError  {

         public static void main(String args []) {
                 System.out.println(MAX_VALUE);
             }

}
```

Can anybody please explain why this program is showing compile time error, if I tried to use imports like 
`import static java.lang.Integer.*;`
 `import static java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE;`, it ran fine and as expected displayed the maximum value of long data types, but with the above imports its showing error.

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: It's an ambiguous name. Both those classes have a `static` field named `MAX_VALUE`. The compiler can't determine which one you want.

Comment: Also try removing the `*` and `.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you must explicitly state what to import in this case since both classes have a `MAX_VALUE` constant.

If you open the source code you'll see.

Since you can't assign an alias in java you are stuck with using `Integer.MAX_VALUE`/`Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Just a side note: I do not suggest a `static` import for `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (nor `Long.MAX_VALUE`) because if you have a rather big class and in the middle you reference `MAX_VALUE` then someone in the future will scratch his head asking ***"Whose max value are we talking about?"***

Comment: with regards to your side note - I've programmed in .Net for the past 15 years and am going through Java to gain experience with it - but are you saying that a Java IDE doesn't exist that has the "go to definition" feature that's in Visual Studio for the past 10 years.

Answer (score 4):

You're importing `MAX_VALUE` twice.

It's included both on `java.lang.Integer.*;` and `java.lang.Long.*;`

Answer (score 0):

In that case you import the static methods and fields associated with the given class.

For instance the `Assert` class contains a lot of methods like `assertEquals`.

Instead of writing each time `Assert.assertEquals`, you can write

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

and then use `assertEquals` in your code.

The reason why this doesn't work is because a call to `MAX_VALUE` is ambiguous between `Long.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`